# Is $E(T) \ge \sigma$ or is $E(T)\le\sigma$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, chi-squared-test, expected-value, inequality

Let $X_1,\cdots X_n \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ be i.i.d., and let $T=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\Sigma^n_{i=1}(X_i^2)}$.

Is $E(T) \ge \sigma$ or is $E(T)\le\sigma$?

My work:

$\frac{X_i^2}{\sigma^2}\sim \chi^2_1$ so I let $T=\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\Sigma^n_{i=1}(X_i^2/\sigma^2)}$.

Now, $E(T)=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}E(\sqrt{\chi^2_n})=\frac{\sigma \sqrt{2} \Gamma((n+1)/2)}{\sqrt{n}\Gamma(n/2)}$.

From here, I do not know how to compare $E(T)$ and $\sigma$. I thought about using Jensen's Inequality, but I don't know how to make that work here.

I suppose my difficulty in finishing this problem is that it's not clear to me whether the numerator or denominator excluding $\sigma$ is greater.

Comment: $E(T)$ _does not_ equal $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n}E(\chi_n^2)$ and so you are barking up the wrong tree here.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Are you able to find my error in calculating $E(T)$?

Comment: $\frac{X_i^2}{\sigma^2}\sim N(0,1)$ ..... Nope

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica I corrected the typos, but I am still getting the same result for $E(T)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Jensen's Inequality

$$E(T)\leq\sqrt{E(T^2)}=\sigma.$$

Comment: So, is the function $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ that you're applying Jensen's inequality to?

Comment: You don't need Jensens inequality for this one; Start with $Var(T)\geq 0$ and expand

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica So I am getting that $E(T^2) \ge E(T)^2$. To use this inequality, I will need to evaluate $E(T)$, correct? I am still not understanding where I am messing up with evaluating my $E(T)$.

Comment: @Edison, you do not need to evaluate $E(T)$ to use this inequality. Also, there is nothing wrong with your evaluation of $E(T)$. The function $$g(x) = \sqrt 2 \ \Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)/\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)$$ is always less than $\sqrt n$, but approaches $\sqrt n$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Showing this is hard. Using Jensen's inequality is easy.

Comment: @knrumsey-ReinstateMonica I see. Thank you for verifying my $E(T)$ was correct. Which function would I apply Jensen's Inequality to here, I am a bit confused.

Comment: @Edison, Although $E(T) \neq \sigma$, it is true that $E(T^2) = \sigma^2$. Application of Jensen's inequality is straightforward from here (as shown in the answer above). $$E\left(\sqrt{T^2}\right) \leq \sqrt{E(T^2)}.$$

Comment: @Edson  from the variance argument we have $\sigma^2 = E(T^2) \geq E(T)^2$ (with equality only when the variance is 0). Why is it difficult to thereby conclude that $\sigma\geq E(T)$ given that both $\sigma$ and $T$ are non-negative?

Comment: @knrumsey-ReinstateMonica How do we know that $E(T^2)=\sigma^2$? Wouldn't the $\sqrt{1/n}$ have to be $\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}}$ for this to be true?

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica I suppose I am having difficulty seeing that $E(T^2)=\sigma^2$. However, given that I know this, your solution is very clear. Thank you!

Comment: @Edison, For unbiasedness, we divide by $n-1$ when $\mu$ is unknown and we divide by $n$ when $\mu$ is known. In your example, $\mu=0$ is known.

Comment: Thank you! @knrumsey-ReinstateMonica